# Name error (undefined local variable 'browser') in an RSpec test for a class that uses the Browser gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, browser, rspec, user-agent, nameerror

I have a class for constructing some user parameters by getting a section of params from a post request and adding some user agent information to them. I'm using the [browser gem](https://github.com/fnando/browser) for this purpose.

The gem adds a helper method called browser, that inspects your current user agent. Its use is as simple as this:

```
require "browser"

browser.name            # readable browser name
browser.version         # major version number
```

A short section of my class looks like so:

```
class AkUserParams
  def self.create(params)
    @user_params = params[:signature]
    @user_params[:user_agent] = browser.user_agent
    @user_params
  end
end
```

Using the browser gem throughout my application works fine. However, when I write a spec in RSpec for the class, I get the following error:

`NameError: undefined local variable or method 'browser' for AkUserParams:Class`

```
describe AkUserParams do

  # I have tried both with and without this before block:
  before :all do
    $browser = Browser.new
  end

  let(:some_params) {{
    signature: {
      name: Faker::Name.name,
      email: Faker::Internet.email,
    }
  }}

  # This is a bogus test I'm expecting to fail. It doesn't get to 
  # failing and instead gives me a name error.

  it 'Builds an object containing data about the user and the action' do
    expect(AkUserParams.create(petition_signature)).to eq(true)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I fixed the issue by just injecting `browser`:

```
class AkUserParams
  def self.create(browser, params)
    @user_params = params[:signature]
    @user_params[:user_agent] = browser.user_agent
    @user_params
  end
end
```

That way I can just `let(:browser) { Browser.new }` in the spec.